# Where are the packages installed in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get, dpkg

Whenever i install a package using the sudo apt-get install command, I would like to know where in the file system the package is palced. Does it get placed in a single folder like in the windows file system, or do the files get placed across different directories?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

list package files:

```
$ dpkg -L <package-name>
```

get package name: (apt install , so you should already know it), you can also list all package and find someone by `grep` command:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep <package-name-keyword>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could use

```
which program
```

To get the location of the executable. If you refer the program data each manufactor has a different location for data. Normally is under /usr/bin of /home/youruser

Trying using

```
ls -al
```

To show hidden folders

Good luck